# Book following a royal descendant with strong hybrid magic

Tags: story-identification, novel

The book I'm looking for opens with a prince and princess that are married and from different kingdoms; people don't like that. They are at a party (not sure what they were celebrating). The princess tastes poison in her cup. She is pregnant and was served juice not wine. They leave the party and get attacked. The prince kills the attacker and runs off to live in some small out of the way village. That is just the prologue.

The rest of the book is about their son and it's stressed that he has blue eyes and a stronger magical ability because of his mixed blood. Also, the village they live in is attacked by some duke looking for glory and thinking it's a bandit village even though is full of farmers and berry pickers.

Comment: I highly advise looking over the questions at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info and seeing which ones you can answer to help us help you.